# What is meant by "onload=foo(event)"?

Tags: javascript, onload

I am new to JS and found this code section:

```
<body>
    <span id="sp1">
        <img src="aurora.gif" onload="ev1(event)">
    </span>        
</body>
```

As far I understood, the `onload` attribute gets triggered if the entire HTML Doc finished "loading".
 But I don't really understand, whats passed to the `ev1` function if the `onload` attribute is triggered. What is `event` in this case?

[Here](https://github.com/CCrashBandicot/helpful/blob/master/CVE-2010-0249.py) is the source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hooking up a handler to the image's `load` event and passing the event object for the event into the handler. The `event` object exists reliably cross-browser within the context of the `onload` attribute-style event handler: On IE, it's a global; on Firefox, it's a local within a synthetic function created for the `onload` handler; on Chrome, I think it's *both*. :-)

Note that the `ev1` function must be a global, which is one of many reasons not to use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers.

Comment: So `event` is basically an empty object of type EventObject which exists automatically when the `onload` attribute gets triggered? Or did I understand you incorrectly?

Comment: @Lavair - It's not empty, it's a normal event object for a `load` event on `img`.

Answer (score 1):

`img` also has [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/image#Attributes) attribute & is called when when the image has finished loading. Similarly it also have `onerror` event handler. `event` represent the event object.

```js
function ev1(e) {
  console.log(e)
  console.log('Img loaded')

}
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://i.redd.it/xbq78cnv2nr21.jpg' onload='ev1(event)'>
```

Comment: so it would be equivalent to write `ev1(this)`? Is event basically the image?

Comment: @Lavair - No. `this` is the `HTMLImageElement`. `event` is the event object for the `load` event. (Both `event.target` and `event.currentTarget` will be the `HTMLImageElement`, though.)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an attempt pass the [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) Object as an argument to a function called `ev1`.

Instead of using an inline event, the <s>author</s> developer should have used a JavaScript event, like this.

```
document.querySelector("img").addEventListener("load", event => {
  console.log(event);
});
```

Good luck.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with inline events, but its preferable to separate your HTML/CSS/JavaScript which is done to improve maintainability.

Comment: *"I'm not sure if this works or not..."* Yes, it does, even on non-IE browsers.

Comment: For more information read [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/86595) from [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/86589).

Comment: Even in Angular you have this special variable `$event`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for clearing that up, I wrote that because I never use inline scripting.

Comment: @LogicalBranch - Not using `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers is very wise. :-) That said, `load` on an `img` is one of the few places where it's probably less error-prone than what many people would do instead.

Comment: This code excerpt is from an IE6 exploit, there was no `querySelector` back then